# Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I noticed that 'Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET' page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) isn't supported no more.  What appeared after ASP.NET 2.0 to replace parameters?

Comment: It's still valid information, its just no longer maintained.

Comment: What specifically is not supported?

Comment: [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a previous comment use the [Microsoft Anti Cross Site Scripting Library/Security Runtime Engine.](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

I would recommend using the AntiXSS on any fields coming from the form to your SQL queries and from your DB back to your form.

To Form:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.Security.Application" %>
<%# Encoder.HtmlAttributeEncode(Eval("FROMDB").ToString()) %>
```

To DB:

```
using Microsoft.Security.Application;
string DBVAR = Encoder.HtmlAttributeEncode(txtField.Text);
```

[How to set up as the default encoder for your web application](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/04/28/using-antixss-4-1-beta-as-the-default-encoder-in-asp-net.aspx)

Documentation is not the best, but it works well as a whitelist approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can always revert to more technology generic but security specific websites such as OWASP with their [OWASP Sql Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) depict C# specific examples on how to protect against this security issue.